# How to fix syntax error in SQLite NTILE statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite, syntax, window-functions

I am trying to execute a query in SQLite that looks like:

```
SELECT var_1, 
var_2, 
NTILE(4) OVER (
  GROUP BY var_1,
  ORDER BY var_3
) AS quartile
FROM
table
```

However, when I try to run this code I get an error message that says 'Error while executing SQL query on database: near "(": syntax error'.

Alternatively, earlier I was getting an error that said, 'Error while executing SQL query on database: no such function: NTILE.'

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

(Please note the the query below works fine.)

```
SELECT var_1, 
var_2, 
var_3
FROM
table
```

Comment: That error is indicative that you're using a version of sqlite too old to support window functions. You need 3.25 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for NTILE() uses 'PARTITION BY' instead of 'GROUP BY', so your query should be:

```
SELECT var_1, 
       var_2, 
       NTILE(4) OVER (
           PARTITION BY var_1
           ORDER BY var_3
       ) AS quartile
FROM
table
```